# Javascript tree time-line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time, tree

I have a tree where the first level of it, represents some consecutive time intervals, and level 2 of it represents time-intervals within the parent time-interval and so on.
I tried using d3's treemap to visualize this tree but it seems to me that, it does not allow me to place the nodes in a line and its shape is 2D but I want it to be linear. Is there any similar tool which I can use?

For example for the following tree:

```
-A:30
    -A1:20
        -A11:10
        -A12:10
    -A2:10
-B:30
-C:30
    -C1:10
    -C2:10
    -C3:10
```

I want something like the following picture with zoom in capability:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found [`icicle`](https://bl.ocks.org/mvanegas10/4a9ee4ddb865e17a301317c66ab5b113) very useful in this case!

[additional link](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-icicle)